# R Heatmap color x-axis labels by group

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using the heatmap function to plot a matrix. Each column in the matrix represents one sample, and I have 4 sample types, each with a different quantity. Can I color the labels along the x-axis by sample type?

```
scaleyellowred <- colorRampPalette(c("lightyellow", "red"), space = "rgb")(10)
heatmap(fitted@H, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, col = scaleyellowred)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind using ggplot2?..

```
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>% select(cut, color, price) %>% 
        group_by(cut, color) %>% summarize(mean.price=mean(price)) -> data.set
data.set %>% ggplot(data=., mapping=aes(x=cut, y=color, fill=mean.price)) + geom_tile() +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(color=rainbow(ncol(data.set))))
```

Comment: No,I don't mind really, but I dont understand what %>% means and I get Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’ (I can install it, but what is it for?)

Comment: ah, %>% is a pipe operator. It actually comes from magrittr package and is quite extensively used for process dataframes. the idea is:
data.frame %>% do smth with it and send the result further %>% do smth else, etc., where %>% means "send further" so to say.. you gonna need dplyr, you can install it with install.packages("dplyr"), it's on cran. it is a popular package for data transformation. I only used it here to create a sample data. Let me know if you need help tuning the plot.

Answer (score 0):

`heatmap.2()` from `gplots` has the `colCol` argument for this. Set up a vector of colour names corresponding to your sample types. For simplicity, let's say they're grouped together in the original matrix.

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(400), ncol=40)
sample.types <- c(rep("Blue", 10), rep("Green", 10), rep("Red", 10), rep("Purple", 10))

library(gplots)
heatmap.2(m, trace="none", colCol = sample.types)
```

[image]

Note that the sample types have retained the correct colour when clustered.